# createMaterialBottomTabNavigator not working in ios

Tags: react-native

I have used 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs' for bottom tab navigation's which is working perfectly fine in android with ripple effect on tab click but ripple effect not working in ios ,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs'; // <- notice where we import createMaterialBottomTabNavigator from
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const tabBarIcon = name => ({ tintColor }) => (
  <MaterialIcons
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
    name={name}
    color={tintColor}
    size={24}
  />
);

const screens = {
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: tabBarIcon('photo-album'),
      tabBarColor: 'blue' // <- set this to the color you want
    }
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: tabBarIcon('favorite'),
      tabBarColor: 'green' // <- set this to the color you want
    }
  }
};

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
  shifting: true,  // <- notice this has been set to true
  activeColor: 'white',
  inactiveColor: 'black'
};

const MainNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(screens, config);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

dependencies from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.6.2",
    "react-native-svg-icon": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` ?

Comment: dependencies from package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.6.2",
    "react-native-svg-icon": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0"
  },

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your dependencies it looks like you haven't followed the instructions for installing `react-navigation` completely.

It would seem that you haven't installed `react-native-reanimated` it would make sense to install this as it is required for `react-navigation`.

You can install it as follows:

> `yarn add react-native-reanimated`
>
> or with npm
>
> `npm install react-native-reanimated`

As you are using a version of react-native greater than `0.60.0` you should be able to rely on the automatic linking. However you may need to reinstall the pods. You can do this by opening a terminal at the root of your project and running the following commands.

```
$ cd ios
$ pod install
$ cd ..
```

Comment: still not showing ripple on ios,actual problem is we are not getting `react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs` in pod file